# Solve the equations for x.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> a. $10e^{2x}=7\cdot 2^{ax}$
>
> b. $\frac{2(a-x)}{3\sqrt[3]{x}}-x^{2/3}=0$

I did both, but I'm not sure if I did them correctly. Here is my work for both questions:

> a. $10e^{2x}=7\cdot 2^{ax}$

$e^{2x}=\frac{7\cdot 2^{ax}}{10}$

$In(\frac{7\cdot 2^{ax}}{10})=2x$

$In(\frac{7}{10})+In(2^{ax})=2x$

$In(\frac{7}{10})+axIn(2)=2x$

$In(\frac{7}{10})=2x-axIn(2)$

$In(\frac{7}{10})=x(2-aIn(2))$

$x=\frac{In(\frac{7}{10})}{2-aIn(2)}$

> b. $\frac{2(a-x)}{3\sqrt[3]{x}}-x^{2/3}=0$

$\frac{2(a-x)}{3\sqrt[3]{x}}=x^{2/3}$

$2(a-x)=3x^{1/3}\cdot x^{2/3}$

$2(a-x)=3x$

$2a-2x=3x$

$2a=5x$

$x=\frac{2a}{5}$

Comment: That is Correct

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any better way or faster?

Comment: I think you found the best way to solve them, congratulations!

Comment: In the answer below, it is pointed out that we have to be careful in exercise $a)$ (denominator could be $0$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a), the real solution (correct):

$$10e^{2x}=7\cdot2^{\text{a}x}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\ln(10e^{2x})=\ln(7\cdot2^{\text{a}x})\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\ln(10)+\ln(e^{2x})=\ln(7)+\ln(2^{\text{a}x})\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$2x+\ln(10)=\ln(7)+\text{a}x\ln(2)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$2x-\text{a}x\ln(2)=\ln(7)-\ln(10)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x(2-\text{a}\ln(2))=\ln(7)-\ln(10)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\frac{\ln(7)-\ln(10)}{2-\text{a}\ln(2)}$$

Where $\text{a}\ln(2)\ne2$

(b) is also correct, but $\text{a}\ne0$.

Comment: You are right with $a)$ . In $b)$ , the case $a=0$ is valid.

Comment: @Peter That was what I was pointing out here.

Comment: Then, I do not understand $a\ne 0$ in exercise $b)$.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand why $a$ cannot be $0$.

Comment: Now, look when $a=0$:

$$2\cdot\frac{0-x}{3\cdot\sqrt[3]{x}}-x^{\frac{2}{3}}=0\Longleftrightarrow-\frac{5x^{\frac{2}{3}}}{3}=0$$

That gives us a solution at $x=0$, but when we check that:

$$2\cdot\frac{0-x}{3\cdot\sqrt[3]{0}}-0^{\frac{2}{3}}$$

Comment: @JanEerland You are right. I did not consider this.

Comment: @Peter You're welcome, when we use a limit then we can get to zero but it has to be in a carefull way! Otherwise you allowed yourself to divide by zero .... kuch

Comment: @JanEerland, thanks. I did not consider this either.

Comment: @C.Guan You're welcome!